# Set method return type to 'void'. Dont quite understand

Tags: java, android, eclipse, background, void

Doing a basic android background service app.
Do not quite understand why there is a error `(MainActivity.java). Error is at         btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);`

The quick fix provided was set return type to 'void'. Whereas for btnStop there is no error.

```
package com.example.backgroundservice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Service;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{




    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart); (ERROR HERE)
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

btnStart.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
});

btnStop.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
});

}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: is it inside `onCreate`? and what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be inside the `onCreate` method.

Before that method is called, your activity is not initialised, so there's no layout, and you can't find any UI element by id.

**EDIT:** Something like that would work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);  // this layout must contain btnStart and btnStop
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart); // variables are declared then allocated
    Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)
    // ...<rest of your code>....
```

Comment: well a compile time error would occur if you don't declare btnStart before you try to allocate it...

Comment: I agree, but that's not what you wrote

Comment: Try: Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

Comment: actually he is going to have, not me

Comment: if initialization fails you get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Do i add it before btnStart.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { or after it?

Answer (score 2):

It should be inside `onCreate`.

```
Button btnStart,btnStop; // should be delcared. i guess you do not have this
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
            btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart); // initialize here
            btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)
            ...// rest of the code
```

I guess you have the below outside `onCreate` (outside any method) and you have not declared `btnStart`

```
      btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
```

But even if you declare you need to inflate the layout first ans then initialize button or else you get `NUllPointerException`.

So Declare the buttons as class member and initialize it in `onCreate` as shown above

Edit:

Since you already have the listener annonymous inner class there is no need for you to implement `OnClickListener` and so you can remove this

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Also your import staments are wrong

Replace this

```
   import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

BY

```
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: Take a notice that the implemented interface is not `View.OnClickListener`. But yes, looks like a beginner code and propably he just made a mistake to import the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You must override the activity onCreate method and set their content:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.theLayoutThatContains_R.id.btnStart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you have code belonging to method body inside a class body. Eclipse notices the syntax error and proposes to "fix" it by changing the code to a method declaration. You don't get any further syntax errors as compilation stopped at the first syntax error.

As others have instructed, the correct place for code like this is the activity's `onCreate()` method.